# Full Calendar customized colors

Tags: jquery-plugins, plugins, fullcalendar, color-picker

I need to add custom color in creating each event in the full calendar (just like in the google calendar- the user can customize the text and bg colors of events).

Do you know any color picker plugins that may best fit to full calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the CSS Class name for a new event.  Like

```
var myEvents = [
  {
    title: 'XMas',
    start: theDate,
    className : 'holiday'
  }
];
```

Then to update the style of the given event *type* do something like the following:

```
#calendar .holiday,
#calendar .holiday div,
#calendar .holiday span {
  background-color: #6d4d47;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #6d4d47;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the fullcalendar documentation... which seems to be down at the moment. You can pass in colours for each event as elements of the array:

```
'backgroundColor' => "#36c",
'borderColor' => "#36c",
'textColor' => "#36c",
```

No plugin needed!